# how to close running batch file for few hours daily

Tags: windows, batch, windows-server-2003

We have a batch file which runs continuously in our windows 2003 server because a Java application is depending upon that.

However, now I wish to close it automatically for half an hour every day at night when we scheduled for automatic backup from the java application.

Can you advise how I can do that? It could be from another batch file or any other way.

Comment: Do you run it using Windows Task Scheduler? Could you set the task to force it to quit after running for 23 hours 30 minutes? (Using the "Stop the task if it runs for..." setting)

Comment: I already tried that but nothing happening with that option. It still remains open.

Comment: Hmmm, strange. That's never failed me before... have you tried using TASKKILL in a separate batch file?

Comment: If it works for you, what do you think I did wrong with the option?  As far as I know, we can kill only .exe with taskkill option, not .bat running file. I already tried to kill cmd.exe with taskkill but that also didn't work out well.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't think of anything that would cause the "Stop the task..." function to fail. And good point on taskkill. Better minds than mine may be required!